# using fromfile_prefix_chars with multiple arguments (nargs="*")

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to use file arguments in python argparse with lines in the file that look like this:

```
--contour_levels=-4 -2 0 2 4
```

or:

```
--contour_levels -4 -2 0 2 4
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I know I can use the first one and then list the other levels one per line but this looks ridiculous.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args

```
def convert_arg_line_to_args(self, arg_line):
    for arg in arg_line.split():
        if not arg.strip():
            continue
        yield arg
```

This function replaces the one the parser uses to read lines from your file.  You could subclass `ArgumentParser` and add this function.  Or you could 'kludge' it by replacing the bound method of the parser with this function (without the `self` - see comment).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(...)
parser.convert_arg_line_to_args = convert_arg_line_to_args
```

The idea is to take a line from your file, and return (as a generator) strings one by one.  If this doesn't work as given, it shouldn't be hard to tweak.

p.s. The default version, which returns one string per line is

```
def convert_arg_line_to_args(self, arg_line):
    return [arg_line]
```

look at the code for `ArgumentParser._read_args_from_files` if you have more questions on how it is used.  This is the function takes the list of strings from `sys.argv[1:]` and returns a new one with your file contents added.

Comment: Thanks. I did try this and got frustrated early on. Two addenda for anyone blindly cutting and pasting like me: the usage above applies only to the override. The kludge should not have the "self" argument.